# Split a dangling meta character, java?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a string which contains as follows:

```
String met="Your number is { 1234}."
```

I need to extract the number "1234" from the string

When I am using the split function, it gives me error of  "dangling meta character"

```
String[] splitMet=met.split("{");
```

How can I use the split function in a dangling meta character case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to just get the number out of String and exclude opening and closing curly braces you can use

```
String[] splitMet=met.split("\\{|\\}");
```

Here I have escaped the `{` & `}` which is a meta character.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to escape it (`\\`) when you are using `meta character`'s in split method, since it takes a regex as a param.

```
String[] splitMet=met.split("\\{");
```

> If you specify this as a literal in the Java programming language, then you need to follow the Java language requirements and escape a backslash within a string literal with yet another backslash:

Full story here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/names/syntax.html

Answer (score 1):

Although Suresh has already answered that you need to escape it using the `\\` ie like

```
String[] splitMet=met.split("\\{");
```

The reason why you are getting this error is because { is a reserved character in Java regex. You can check the [pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) here for details.